# Does anybody know where can I find the datasheet of this LCD?

Tags: identification, lcd

Where can I find the datasheet of this LCD?
[image: this lcd]
All I know about this LCD is that it's probably 128*128 and some of the text I found on the LCD:
`128128I1NA FP-4`,`01-SB7064`,`HILS-R-0`,`RoHS 1003`
and it has 26 pins(the 27th is not used). It has three colours: red white and green.

Comment: The title doesn’t match the question. Simply, you want the datasheet for the display.

Comment: yea but I can't find any info 'bout it.

Comment: This I understand. Where did the lcd come from? It could be custom and thus no datasheet is available. Post a picture of the rear. With the cost of lcd modules these days, you’d be better of just buying something that is known rather than trying to get data on a weirdass display.

Comment: I found some alternate lcd that is similar on some shopping websites, but im not sure if they are similar. plus its connected to a microprocessor that has its own datasheet. WHat do you mean by the rear?

Comment: I remember having a small nokia lcd that has its own datasheet, but the connector broke. So i only left with this lcd.